# Read data in content type via CSOM

Tags: sharepoint, content-type, csom

I have an issue with CSOM and content type, I used CSOM to read some value in a sharepoint list, it works well until I try to used content type If I create a new content type with my fields, it's worked but if I add my field in an existing content type. It doesn't work and that's return me the following error:

```
Error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

Here a piece of code from where my error is comming:

```
 List list = web.Lists.GetByTitle("myList");
    CamlQuery query = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery();
    ListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(query);
    l_objCtx.Load(items, its => its.Include(item => item[ColumnName], item => item.Id));
    l_objCtx.ExecuteQuery();

    foreach (var item in items)
    {
          m_strGetprimary = item.Id.ToString();
          return true;
    }
```

I've done a lot of researches but I found nothing related to this issue

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

After adding SharePoint field to existing content type please check field name that you have just added. Sometimes it can be different and then your variable **ColumnName** might have wrong text value.

How to check it:

1. Go to site settings > Site content types > *Your content type*.
2. Select/click your field and in URL you will have param **Field**={*field name*}.